# Can i devolop c# gui applications on mac without using xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, visual-studio

Im a student and i started learning C#. Im currently using a macbook air. I wanna know if there is a way to create gui applications without alternating between xcode and visual studio.

Comment: You can use any text editor you want alongside the c# compiler.  Using an IDE is easier though.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Xamarin: You can develop iOS and Android apps:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin/mobile-apps

Comment: You can also use Xamarin.Forms to develop Desktop applications for Windows, Linux and macOS